# How to extend DOM FileList type so I can array filter?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've tried several different ways of getting my [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) filtered without getting any typescript types error. I've gotten it to work with a simple [for-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). But with the power of arrow functions, it's a one-liner vs the couple lines with for-loop. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance. Please see below for what I've tried so far.

```js
onDrop(evt: DragEvent) {
  let files: FileList = evt.dataTransfer.files;

  // results in: Property 'item' is missing in type 'File[]' but required in type 'FileList'.ts(2741)

  files = Array.from(files).filter((file: File) => file.type === 'text/csv');


  // Type 'FileList' is not an array type.ts(2461)
  [...files].filter((file: File) => file.type === 'text/csv');
}
```

```js
// no type errors
const filteredFileList = [];
for (let index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
  const file: File = files[index];
  if (file.type === 'text/csv') {
    filteredFileList.push(file);
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to set `File[]` to `FileList`, and you can't do that because those are two different types and do not inherit from one another.

You need to save the `File[]` to a new variable like you are doing in your for loop.

```
onDrop(evt: DragEvent) {
  let files: FileList = evt.dataTransfer.files;

  const filteredFileList: File[] = [...files].filter((file: File) => file.type === 'text/csv');
}
```

You will need to add `"dom.iterable"` to your `libs` list and use a target of `es2015` or later in order to support converting `FileList` to `File[]` using `[...files]`.

Comment: which version of typescript are you using? I'm on 3.2.4 and I still get the same errors.

Comment: I am using 3.3.1

Comment: what does your `tsconfig.json` look like? The issue could be there

Comment: Add `"dom.iterable"` to your `lib` array.

Comment: now i get the following. Type 'FileList' is not an array type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.ts(2568)

Comment: I then also changed the target: `"target": "es2017"` also `es2015`, `es2016` work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188237/discussion-between-alphapilgrim-and-get-off-my-lawn).